# Why does liferay test for warnEnabled before logging a warning?

Tags: liferay-6

I often see the following in liferay source code:

```
if (_log.isWarnEnabled()) {
    _log.warn(message);
}
```

What is the rationale behind the `isWarnEnabled` test ? Isn't that perfomed by the _log.warn ?

Alain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for perfomance issues,
`_log.warn(message);` will produce the information to be logged,
`log.isWarnEnabled()` avoids this "expensive" operation.

See [apache commons doc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging//apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/Log.html)